# Can't find error with MS Access SQL FROM Clause Syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Select distinct [Doc Type], [Customer Number], count([Customer Number]) , [T] From (
Select distinct A.[Customer Number] & A.[Membership Number], A.[Customer Number] , B.[Doc Type ], B.[SumOpenAmount] From(
SELECT distinct [Doc Type] , [Customer Number], Sum([Open Amount]) as T  FROM Data Where [Doc Type] = 'RU')B, [Data] A
Where B.[Customer Number] = A.[Customer Number] Group by [Doc Type]) 
group by [Doc Type], [Customer Number]
having count([Customer Number]) = 1
```

Throwing an Error that Doc Type could refer to more than 1 table listed in the from clause of your SQL Statement

Comment: Is `&` a valid MS Access operator? What does it mean?

Comment: Yes It concatenates two columns together to the best of my knowledge

Comment: The inner GROUP BY looks strange. Wrong subquery?

Comment: Prefix `[Doc Type]` with its table name/alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your query has a number of syntax and suboptimal issues:

1. **GROUP BY**: In aggregate queries that contain non-aggregated columns in `SELECT` clause, `GROUP BY` must be used. Some dialects allow `GROUP BY` columns to be omitted but not Access SQL. Also, `DISTINCT` is not necessary for `GROUP BY`.
2. **ALIASES**: Whenever subqueries and joins are utilized, always use table aliases to avoid name collision for both derived tables and column aliases for *all* expressions. Additionally, avoid A, B, C ... for more informative aliases including T. See [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).
3. **EXPLICIT JOIN**: Use the current ANSI SQL standard of explicit joins and not the outdated implicit joins that use `WHERE`. See [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins).

Therefore, consider following adjustments that employ the above guidelines.

```sql
SELECT [doc type]
     , [customer number]
     , COUNT([customer number]) As CountCustomerNumber          -- ALIAS ADDED
     , SUM([SumOpenAmount]) As TotalOpenAmount                  -- AGGREGATED COLUMN
FROM   
      (SELECT d.[customer number] & d.[membership number] AS CustMemb  -- ALIAS ADDED
            , d.[customer number]
            , agg.[doc type]
            , SUM(agg.[TotalSubOpenAmount]) AS SumOpenAmount    -- AGGREGATED COLUMN
        FROM  (SELECT [doc type]
                    , [customer number]
                    , SUM([open amount]) AS TotalSubOpenAmount  -- INFORMATIVE ALIAS
               FROM   data
               WHERE  [doc type] = 'RU'
               GROUP BY [doc type]
                      , [customer number]
              ) agg                                             -- INFORMATIVE ALIAS
        INNER JOIN [data] d                                     -- INNER JOIN USED
           ON  d.[customer number] = agg.[customer number]
        GROUP  BY d.[customer number] & d.[membership number]   -- GROUP BY COLUMNS ADDED
                , d.[customer number]
                , agg.[doc type]
      ) AS sub                                                  -- ALIAS ADDED
GROUP  BY [doc type]
        , [customer number]
HAVING COUNT([customer number]) = 1
```

<sup>**Note**: Since Access does not support comments in queries. Remove all `--` messages before running.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a good reason to do [aliasing](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). I think what's happening is your innermost (`data`) subquery is returning `doctype` (becomes `b` as part of the outer subquery), and `a` also has a `doc type`. You can also remove the inner `Group By` clause, because it's done on the outermost query; the results should be the same.

I also noticed that you do this: `A.[Customer Number] & A.[Membership Number]` and then don't do anything with the column. If you want to do something with that, you should name the Column. I named it `CMN` below, you can pick whatever you want.

Am I correct that you're also doing an implicit `JOIN` with the line `) as B, [Data] A`? If so, you should consider making that explicit, or you may end up with undesired matches.

If that's what you want, do this:

```
-- as B, [Data] A
++ as B LEFT JOIN [Data] as A on a.[Customer Number] = b.[Customer Number]
```

This way, you can get rid of your `Where B.[Customer Number] = A.[Customer Number]`  line (after testing, of course), and you'll end up with a more explicitly defined `JOIN`. See bottom for what that looks like.

The first `Group by [Doc Type]` is what's tripping you up.

When referring to fields, it's my personal preference to always add an alias unless I'm only working with a simple oneliner, with one table/view, even if there aren't any fields with similar names, because I usually end up with duplicate names in the future. Even then, I try to add aliases, because then later if I decide I want to add more fields/tables it doesn't make me re-factor the whole thing.

**Try this (if you're not doing implicit `JOIN`):**

```
Select distinct c.[Doc Type], c.[Customer Number], c.CMN, count(c.[Customer Number]) , c.[T] 
From (
    Select distinct (A.[Customer Number] & A.[Membership Number]) as CMN, A.[Customer Number] , B.[Doc Type], B.[SumOpenAmount] 
    From(
        SELECT distinct d.[Doc Type] , d.[Customer Number], Sum(d.[Open Amount]) as T  
        FROM Data as d
        Where d.[Doc Type] = 'RU'
        ) as B, [Data] A
    Where B.[Customer Number] = A.[Customer Number] 
    ) as C
group by C.[Doc Type], C.[Customer Number], C.CMN
having count(C.[Customer Number]) = 1
```

**Do this if you want to have an explicit `JOIN` (recommended):**

```
Select distinct c.[Doc Type], c.[Customer Number], c.CMN, count(c.[Customer Number]) , c.[T] 
From (
    Select distinct (A.[Customer Number] & A.[Membership Number]) as CMN, A.[Customer Number] , B.[Doc Type], B.[SumOpenAmount] 
    From(
        SELECT distinct d.[Doc Type] , d.[Customer Number], Sum(d.[Open Amount]) as T  
        FROM Data as d
        Where d.[Doc Type] = 'RU'
        ) as B 
    LEFT JOIN [Data] as A on a.[Customer Number] = b.[Customer Number]
    ) as C
group by C.[Doc Type], C.[Customer Number], C.CMN
having count(C.[Customer Number]) = 1
```

(Removed extra spaces)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the B.[DOC TYPE ] in the sub-query has an extra space in the field name.
Also, the sub-query does not reference the inner sub-query's [T] field and as such it will not be available to the main query unless it is in the Data table.
Finally, the outer sub-query's group by does not specify which data source the [Doc Type] is coming from for the grouping.

Try this

```
Select distinct 
    [Doc Type], 
    [Customer Number], 
    count([Customer Number]), 
    [T] 
From 
    (
        Select 
            distinct A.[Customer Number] & A.[Membership Number], 
            A.[Customer Number] , 
            B.[Doc Type], 
            B.[T] 
        From
            (
                SELECT distinct 
                    [Doc Type] , 
                    [Customer Number], 
                    Sum([Open Amount]) as T  
                FROM 
                    Data 
                Where [Doc Type] = 'RU'
            )B, 
            [Data] A
        Where B.[Customer Number] = A.[Customer Number] 
        Group by B.[Doc Type]
    ) 
group by [Doc Type], [Customer Number]
having count([Customer Number]) = 1
```